# SuiteScript Approve SaleOrder

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Hi I need to Approve a SaleOrder in suitescript 2.0 is a suitelet, I dont know Why setValue doesnt take effect, I dont get error,

here the code:

```
    function onRequest(context) {

        var objClass = {};

        if (context.request.method === 'GET') {

    
            var idRecord=29189418;

            //var SO = record.load({ type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, id: idRecord, true });
            var SO = record.load({ type:  record.Type.SALES_ORDER, id: idRecord ,isDynamic: false});
       
            SO.setValue({fieldId:'orderstatus',value:'B'});
                SO.save();
                //SO.save({ ignoreMandatoryFields: true });
     
            
   
            var form = buildForm(context);

            

             context.response.writePage(form);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I found out that script  its correct, the problem was a "beforesubmit script" from 4 years ago was conflicting with the script.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it's a status. You can't set status.
A status is present to say what is the current status of a transaction.

Try to transform it into a fulfillment request.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4267258715.html#bridgehead_4327469981

Answer (score 0):

I found out that script its correct, the problem was a "beforesubmit script" from 4 years ago was conflicting with the script and setting orderstatus='A' back again.